# How to show multidimensional data in my CanvasJS chart?

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, mysql, javascript, array

```
<?php
$db->setQuery("SELECT MartabehName, COUNT(MartabehCode) FROM `#__dimteacher` GROUP BY MartabehName");
$countMartabehName = $db->loadObjectList(); 

foreach($countMartabehName as $row) {
    foreach($row as $key => $data) {
        echo $data."<br />";
    }
}
foreach($countMartabehName as $row) {

$dataPoints = array(
    array("label"=> $row->MartabehName , "y"=> $row->$key)
);
      }

?>
<script>
    my chart code from https://canvasjs.com/
    .
    .
    ,
    .
    .
</script>

<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js">
</script>
```

[image]

How can I show **all array** (datax1,.... datax4) in chart?

It is only displaying the last array member in chart (datax4).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your original coding attempt is repeatedly overwriting the `$dataPoints` variable inside of the loop -- this is why you only see the last iteration's data.

To create the desired multidimensional array directly from the query's result set, here is the way to use column aliases and Joomla's query building syntax.

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true)
    ->select("MartabehName AS label, COUNT(MartabehName) AS y")
    ->from("#__dimteacher")
    ->group("MartabehName");
// echo $query->dump();
$db->setQuery($query);
$dataPoints = $db->loadAssocList();
```

Now your `$dataPoints` variable is instantly ready to deliver to CanvasJS without any manual looping/preparation.

See the result set building method [loadAssocList() in the Joomla docs](https://docs.joomla.org/Selecting_data_using_JDatabase#loadAssocList.28.29).

You can even ORDER BY if you like: https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/23704/12352

As for how you pass your result set to CanvasJS, I don't use CanvasJS, but I'd be very likely to use json instead of feeding it an html table.

```
let chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
    data: [
      {
        dataPoints: <?php echo json_encode($dataPoints, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); ?>
      }
    ]
});

chart.render();
```

Comment: In table loop only change to `$row->label` to `$row[label]`
tank you good man @mickmackusa

Comment: This is for a one-dimensional array: https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/24143/12352  but you can probably adjust it to suit your multidimensional array.  See how `implode()` makes the row generation easier.

Comment: ok i do it tank you man this is my code  `echo '<td>' , implode('</td><td>', $row) , '</td>';` @mickmackusa

Comment: Have you seen alternative ways to pass your result set data to CanvasJS? I don't use CanvasJS, but I'd prefer to pass json into it.  Perhaps consider my updated answer.

Comment: yes it is work it pass my result set data to CanvasJS

Answer (score 0):

**solved**
by changing

```
foreach($countMartabehName as $row) {
    $dataPoints = array(
        array("label"=> $row->MartabehName , "y"=> $row->$key)
    );
}
```

to

```
$dataPoints = array();
foreach($countMartabehName as $row){
    array_push($dataPoints, array("label"=> $row->MartabehName , "y"=> $row->$key));
}
```

it is **not need** when we use **@mickmackusa** cods in first answer